# Python 2.6 + PIL + Google App Engine issue

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I am using OS X 1.6 snow leopard and I successfully got PIL installed. I am able to open terminal and type import Image without any errors.

However, When using app engine I get Image error still saying that PIL is not installed. I am wondering if any of you have an thoughts as to how I can resolve this issue.

-Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Google provides the PIL in the `google.appengine.api.images` module.   You can see examples on how to use it in the [App Engine Documentation - Using the Images Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html).

Comment: To use their images API in the SDK, you have to install PIL yourself: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL.html

Comment: Which he has already done *successfully* on his local machine.  You don't need to install it on app engine itself.  The issue is that he's trying to access it as `Image` and that's not what the module is named on GAE

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and found in GoogleAppEngineLauncher | Preferences that I needed to set the Python Path to /usr/local/bin/python2.5

After I did that it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PIL with Appengine; it uses C extensions and won't run in the sandbox environment.  You do need to have PIL installed on your local machine to use the images API in dev_appserver, because the SDK version of the images API itself uses PIL, but this doesn't mean you can use all of PIL through the images API; the images API is fairly limited.

Additionally, it's a good idea to use Python 2.5 for development, as the production environment uses version 2.5.2 and not all Python 2.6 syntax will work in production (notably "except FooError as bar"), and the purpose of the development server is to test that your code will work right in production.

Answer (score 0):

What David Scott said is actually correct.

I had the errors blow running and couldn't for the heck of me couldn't resolve the issue no matter what patches I tried. What worked for me apparently, was simply changing the Python directory found on C:\python27_x64 and target the pythonw.exe file using the Google App Engine.

FYI, I run with Windows 8.1

---

File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 127, in 
    run_file(**file**, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 123, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5399, in 
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5390, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2980, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5046, in **call**
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3793, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3814, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py", line 243, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=runtime))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 424, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
2015-02-08 17:42:53 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.

Answer (score -1):

How did you install PIL?  If I remember correctly, I had to install it via MacPorts to get the App Engine SDK to recognize that it was installed.

You should probably install Python 2.5 and use that, while you're at it, since that is the Python version that App Engine uses and developing against 2.6 locally could potentially lead to surprising issues when you deploy your app.

Comment: follow this guys steps on a clean install of snow leopard. If you have installed Python after the fact I am not sure it will work.

http://proteus-tech.com/blog/cwt/install-pil-in-snow-leopard/